# CLEARCASE_XPN not parsed as variable in clearcase command

Tags: clearcase

I meet a problem that when I run clearcase command:

```
ct find . -branch 'brtype(my_branch)' -exec "echo %CLEARCASE_XPN%"`
```

`%CLEARCASE_XPN%` not parsed as a variable and the output is:

```
%CLEARCASE_XPN%
%CLEARCASE_XPN%
%CLEARCASE_XPN%
...
```

But I'm sure `CLEARCASE_XPN` is the variable denotes the whole path of the found file.
Can anybody help? OS is linux, shell is tcsh, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
ct find . -branch 'brtype(my_branch)' -exec 'echo $CLEARCASE_XPN'
```

`%CLEARCASE_XPN%` is a windows syntax.

`$CLEARCASE_XPN` is the unix syntax, that you can use in your Linux tcsh session.

See "[`cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm)" and "[Additional examples of the cleartool find command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425)" for many examples using the unix syntax.

---

Note also the use of simple quotes around the exec directive: `-exec 'echo $CLEARCASE_XPN'`.
That will prevent the shell itself to interpret *immediately* the `$CLEARCASE_XPN` variable (which is unknow for the tcsh session) and will allow the cleartool find to pass the right *value* to the exec directive, replacing `$CLEARCASE_XPN` with the extended pathname.

See "[String quoting (single quote) vs. Weak Quoting (double quote)](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html#uh-8)":

> - **Strong quoting** prevents characters from having special meanings, so if you put a character inside single quotes, what you see is what you get.
>     Therefore, if you are not sure if a character is a special character or not, use strong quotation marks.
> - **Weak quotation** marks treat most characters as plain characters, but allow certain characters (or rather meta-characters) to have a special meaning. As the earlier example illustrates, the backslash within double quotation marks is a special meta-character.
>     It indicates the next character is not, so it can be used before a backslash and before a double quotation mark, escaping the special meaning.
>     There are two other meta-characters that are allowed inside double quotation marks: the dollar sign, and the back quote.

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't work. The feedback is: CLEARCASE_XPN: Undefined variable.

Comment: @Kery Try with simple quotes: `-exec 'echo $CLEARCASE_XPN'`

Comment: @Kery Excellent. I have edited the answer to reflect the use of single quotes (aka "strong quoting") and to explain it.