# New clearcase elements while delivering to the target

Tags: clearcase

[image]I am using ClearCase 8.0 with CQ UCM integration in all windows enviroment.
here is the scenerio I am running into:
I deliver an activity that has a new element. I am noticing that in situations when I do not complete the delivery and back out, and turn around to redeliver the same work, ClearCase is skipping that element. My workaround is to recreate the element and that is time consuming and counter intuitive. Could some one please explain why it's like that and how to have a fix for it.

Regards.
NP

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how/when you "back out".

If, after backing out, that element still has a new version in the target branch (associated to the target stream to which you were delivering), and has a [red merge arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7464236/6309), then this element would always been skipped at the next deliver.
One workaround would be in that case to delete the target version ([`rmver`, to be done carefully](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11795317/6309))

Comment: Hi Von,I am unable to attach an image??? I am backing out the delivery prior to the completion, normal way. All the code gets reverted. The version tree shows that there is a branch (0) created in the target even after the delivery got cancelled. Next time when I try to deliver the same work, same element is reported as spipped. What am I missing? Last time, I did rmver using the gui (version tree) and that did not fix the issue and I guess ClearCase got even more annoyed. Thanks.

Comment: So you don't see any red merge arrow after backout? If it is skipped, can you right click on it and select "element log" (or "merge log") and see if there is any helpfull message?

Comment: Thanks Von, I had a scenerio yesterday but don't have one today. I tried to create one small scenerio where I do not impact a whole lot of elements but CQs have dependency and cannot take just one CQ at this point. Is there a way I can attach a file so I can describe it better? I actually need some urgent help with this. My direct email is npnetflix@hotmail.com if you can shoot me an email I can send the attachment that way.

Comment: Not right now, but you can at least edit your question

Comment: I did, see how the branch(0) is left in the target even after the delivery got reverted. Now when I attempt the delivery again, it is getting skipped. Also interestingly, the element gets skipped even if I chose a different target. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @user3365116 If a second deliver doesn't work, I would recommend a non-UCM merge with findmerge: http://stackoverflow.com/a/684928/6309