# Deleting a Powerbuilder object from ClearCase source control without losing version history?

Tags: version-control, clearcase, powerbuilder

Is there a way to delete a Powerbuilder object from a ClearCase controlled PB target in the Powerbuilder interface without removing the object from source control altogether, i.e. keep version history intact? The only option I see is "Remove from Source Control" which claims it deletes all revision history for that object. Using PB 10.5.2, CC 7.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it claims to "deletes all revision history for that object" (even though this isn't documented in "[To remove objects from ClearCase using PowerBuilder](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.int.doc/topics/pb_int/t_rm_obj_fr_cc89.htm)"), that would make that operation:

- similar to a a [`cleartool rmver`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmver.htm?cp=SSSH27_7.1.2%2F8-0-0-1-62&lang=en) ([which is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11795317/6309))
- quite different from a [`cleartool rmname`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmname.htm?cp=SSSH27_7.1.2%2F8-0-0-1-59&lang=en) ([which is safer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17729901/6309))

You could then fall back to the command line and try a `cleartool rmname` of the file, before refreshing the PB targert in the PB GUI.

Comment: @broetchen yes, and I have fixed the links

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by working outside PB. Remove the line for the object from the PBG file and commit the changes in ClearCase. Then move the object wherever you want it using ClearCase tools. When you refresh in PB the object will show as not source controlled and you can just delete it.